# How can I check whether a option already exist in select by JQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I check whether a option already exist in select by JQuery?

I want to dynamically add options into select and so I need to check whether the option is already exist to prevent duplication.

Answer (score 402, accepted):

This evaluates to true if it already exists:

```
$("#yourSelect option[value='yourValue']").length > 0;
```

Comment: Upgrading to Jquery 1.6 +, enclose yourValue in quotes

Comment: Yep. Quotes are very important.

Comment: Works for me in jquery 1.7.1 without enclosing yourValue in quotes

Comment: How can ignore case or toLowerCase be implemented in the above solution? Would this required a $.each for the drop down list?

Comment: @BenSewards you can easily create your own selectors by extending jquery, however using a function like `.toLowerCase()` in a selector is a bad idea, it could be very slow

Comment: if we want to implement case sensitive matching then what we have to do? use the simple $.each function?

Answer (score 28):

Another way using jQuery:

```
var exists = false; 
$('#yourSelect  option').each(function(){
  if (this.value == yourValue) {
    exists = true;
  }
});
```

Comment: -1 You're basically doing the loop yourself instead of letting jQuery do it like all the other answers. Although this would work, it's re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: not sure it is -1 worthy. this explicitly shows the process, which can be good for beginners. Certainly not the best answer, but it is a valid one.

Comment: And some like the manual approach, like me.  This also combines the step of adding the boolean in there, instead of producing the 0 or 1 like the other does and having to convert it.  I say both approaches are fine because you have to do 2 steps, either way.  This seems more visible to the process, to me, and less prone to error by not judging the length of whitespace, for instance, like `.length` might do.

Comment: Plus one for these, also you don't need to worry for characters in yourValue

Comment: This and alnort29's answer are actually the best way to check for an existing value, if you do not know what "yourValue" is (for example, if it's user input). Building a single string just to let "jQuery do it" would require you to do input sanitization, and you end up with code practices that have haunted SQL for decades. So a -1 is completely unwarranted. The question even states that they want to insert values "dynamically". Don't patch your string together dynamically. You also don't do 'select 1 from users where password="' + string + '"', do you?

Answer (score 22):

```
if ( $("#your_select_id option[value=<enter_value_here>]").length == 0 ){
  alert("option doesn't exist!");
}
```

Comment: you're missing a closing bracket "option[value=<enter_value_here>]"

Answer (score 22):

```
var exists = $("#yourSelect option")
               .filter(function (i, o) { return o.value === yourValue; })
               .length > 0;
```

This has the advantage of automatically escaping the value for you, which makes random quotes in the text much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 12):

Although most of other answers worked for me I used .find():

```
if ($("#yourSelect").find('option[value="value"]').length === 0){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Does not work, you have to do this:

```
if ( $("#your_select_id option[value='enter_value_here']").length == 0 ){
  alert("option doesn't exist!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.  Rather than run the search through the dom every time though the loop for the select control I saved the jquery select element in a variable and did this:

```
function isValueInSelect($select, data_value){
    return $($select).children('option').map(function(index, opt){
        return opt.value;
    }).get().includes(data_value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's help me :

```
  var key = 'Hallo';

   if ( $("#chosen_b option[value='"+key+"']").length == 0 ){
   alert("option not exist!");

    $('#chosen_b').append("<option value='"+key+"'>"+key+"</option>");
    $('#chosen_b').val(key);
   $('#chosen_b').trigger("chosen:updated");
                         }
  });
```