# How can I check whether a option already exist in select by Prototype

Tags: prototypejs

How can I check whether a option already exist in select by Prototype?

I want to dynamically add options into select and so I need to check whether the option is already exist to prevent duplication.

I already See the same question with Jquery, but i try and try without success to do it with Prototype.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I assume the other question you infer is [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/646317/471559). It would appear all that needs to be done is replace `$` with `$$`. What goes wrong when you try?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var exists = false;
$$('select#some-select-id option').each(function(el){
   if(el.value == val_to_check)
   {
      exists = true;
      throw $break;
   }
});

if(!exists) //add option
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate, less verbose alternative would be to use Prototype's `find()` method:

```
var exists = !!$$('select#some-select-id option').find(function(el){ return el.value == val_to_check });
```