# check if Select option already exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check whether a option already exist in select by JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646317/how-can-i-check-whether-a-option-already-exist-in-select-by-jquery)

I have

```
<select name="saved" class="saved" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1">Hello</option>
<option value="2">Goodbye</option>
<option value="3">Wave</option>
</select>
```

how would I have Jquery check if there is already an option with value="2" in "saved" in an if statement

I am looking to see if it exists - not if it is selected.

---

I am using this in a function which may operate on more than one select box. the class name of the select box is now stored as a var "theSel" - how can I modify this for that

---

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `length` property:

```
if ($('select.saved option[value="2"]').length) {
   // exists
}
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // ...
    if ($('select.'+theSel+' option[value="'+theValue+'"]').length) {
       // exists
    }
})
```

Comment: one more question - I didn't realize was a problem until this didn't work for me, the value is being stored in a var as theValue do I do the same?

Comment: @JamesStafford It didn't work for you? What does `theSel` variable store?

Comment: it didnt work because my value is actually stored as theValue and I guessed 

if ($('select.'+theSel+' option[value=theValue]').length) {
I also tried
if ($('select.'+theSel+' option[value='+theValue+']').length) {

theSel does store the class (and/or[they are the same]) name of the select box we are searching against

Comment: the new script is reporting the value already exists (every time) even though there is nothing in the box already (at all)

Comment: @JamesStafford Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jhstaffo/mADM9/1/   however it has a php call and pulls from a mysql database

Comment: @JamesStafford It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/by2Uc/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17790/discussion-between-james-stafford-and-undefined)

Answer (score 3):

```
if( $('.saved option[value="2"]').length ){
   alert('Found !!')
}
```

OR

```
if( $('.saved').has('option[value="2"]')){
   alert('Found !!')
}​
```

You can use either `.length` property or  `.has()`

[CHECK FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/YRJSq/1/)

Comment: ok I have one more continuation of this - I am using this in a function which may operate on more than one select box. the class name of the select box is now stored as a var "theSel" - how can I modify this for that

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('.saved option[value="2"]').length >0) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`attribute equals` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) like this:

```
if($('select[name="saved"] > option[value="5"]').length > 0) {
    console.log("Already exists");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $("option[value='" + theValue + "']", "select." + theSel).length > 0 ) {

    // option exists

}
```

where `theValue` is your stored value, `theSel` is your stored class name.