# Check if an option already exists in a multi select box using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

My question is same as this - [How can I check whether a option already exist in select by JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646317/how-can-i-check-whether-a-option-already-exist-in-select-by-jquery)

Although I want to know how it can be done using JavaScript rather than using jQuery.
I've tried using the `indexOf()` ,  `===` among other things, but I'm not sure if my approach is correct.

P.S : If you're marking it as a duplicate, do link me with the question that has the answer in JavaScript. Thank you.

Also, reasons for down voting are welcome.

My approach :

```
var foldersList = document.getElementById("folders");
    for(var i=0; i<foldersList.length; i++)
    {
       if(!(foldersList.options[i].value.indexOf("someValue") === -1))
       {
             //do something
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you show your approach, and tell why you think it is not correct? `document.querySelectorAll('select option[value="something"]').length > 0` ?

Comment: Can you show how you tried to do it and tell us what exactly didn't work?

Comment: I iterated through the select box to search for the value, is that a correct approach?

Comment: I am guessing the element with id `folders` was your select. In that case it didn't work because a `select` DOM element does not have an `options` attribute.

Comment: @ivarni where is the `options` attribute in OPs code?

Comment: oh, a `multi-select`doesn't have `options` attribute?

Comment: It seems that `foldersList.length` should be `foldersList.options.length`.

Comment: @putvande in the if-clause? Now I just noticed it's not in the for-loop. I did create a plnkr with a select in it and at least in my debugger it didn't have a `options` attribute.

Comment: @ivarni—Select elements **do** have an [*options*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-options) collection. @jack—Select elements **do** have a [*length*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#dom-select-length) property that is the number of options (i.e. the length of the select's *options* collection).

Comment: @RobG Then I stand corrected. Thanks. Current status: "trying to figure out why I'm not seeing it". But it's in the spec so I guess I did a booboo somewhere in my plnkr.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll):

```
document.querySelectorAll('#yourSelect option[value="yourValue"]').length > 0
```

Thats the same as:

```
$("#yourSelect option[value='yourValue']").length > 0;
```

Comment: Descendant selectors doesn't work in IE8 if memory serves me right. Though, really, it's about time we stopped targetting IE8.

Comment: @ivarni—it's not so much about "targeting" IE8, but supporting users who use it, which is about 1/4 of IE users (depending on whose statistics you believe, of course). :-)

Comment: While "target" probably wasn't the best choice of words, I still think we need to move on from IE8 soon. Yes, people are using it, but us supporting that does not help them migrate from it.

Answer (score 2):

The simple way, supported even by the most antique browsers:

```
function selectHasOption(select, value)
{
    for (var i = 0, len = select.options.length; i != len; ++i) {
        if (select.options[i].value == value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And this is the expression:

```
selectHasOption(document.getElementById('folders'), 'someValue')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourSelect = document.getElementById("yourSelect");
for (i = 0; i < yourSelect.length; ++i) {
   if (yourSelect.options[i].value == "someValue") {
      alert("someValue is available");
   }
}
```