# Javascript adding and removing a select option

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add and remove a select option based on another field. There are plenty of answers on this site about adding and removing an option, but I need to only add the option if it doesn't already exist. So far I have:

```
function setCustomerOptions() {
    var customers = getField('select', 'Customer');
    if (getField('select', 'Campaign Type').value == 'Game' || getField('select', 'Campaign Type').value == 'Innovation') {
        for (var i=0; i<customers.length; i++) {
            if (customers.options[i].text == 'N/A') {
                customers.remove(i);
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ($.inArray('N/A', customers.options.text) == -1) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = 'N/A';
            opt.innerHTML = 'N/A';
            customers.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
}
```

This successfully adds and removes the 'N/A' option, however if I select anything other than my initial conditions I keep getting an additional 'N/A' added. I thought the Jquery inArray might help but no.

How can I find if a select option doesn't currently exist?

Comment: Can you place your code in a JSFiddle example? and show the getField definition since I don't see it

Comment: Here's a link to a similar question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/646317/how-can-i-check-whether-a-option-already-exist-in-select-by-jquery

Comment: I've added the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/imonkey/5u5hp7z2/4/ where it is actually working. My code base is Sharepoint 2007, which is why I'm using the getField to make selection by title rather than id. There could be some other Sharepoint "features" working that is causing the /N/A/ to be added multiple times?

Comment: I realised I didn't turn on the jquery library in the jsfiddle. When I did it kept re-adding the new option even if it already existed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get either jquery option to work [thanks for finding the similar question Steven] so ended up doing it long hand with plain javascript:

```
function setCustomerOptions() {
    var customers = getField('select', 'Customer');
    if (getField('select', 'Campaign Type').value == 'Game' || getField('select', 'Campaign Type').value == 'Innovation') {
        for (var i=0; i<customers.length; i++) {
            if (customers.options[i].text == 'N/A') {
                customers.remove(i);
            }
        }
    } else {
        for (var i=0; i<customers.length; ++i) {
            if (customers.options[i].text == "N/A") {
                var optexist = 1;
                break;
            } else {
                var optexist = 0;
            }
        }
        if (optexist == 0) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.value = 'N/A';
            opt.innerHTML = 'N/A';
            customers.appendChild(opt);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
<form>
  <select id="mySelect" size="8">
    <option>Apple</option>
    <option>Pear</option>
    <option>Banana</option>
    <option>Orange</option>
  </select>
</form>
<br>


<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Insert option</button>
<button onclick="myremove()">Remove</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Kiwi";
    x.add(option);
}
function myremove() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    x.remove(x.selectedIndex);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This isn't checking the new option to see if the option already exists. **"only add the option if it doesn't already exist"**