# jquery - check if certain item is present in the select option case

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have something like this

```
 <select name="mname" id="mid" size="15">

                    <option>TextA </option>

                    <option>TextB </option>

                    <option>TextC </option>
        </select>
```

How do I check for the presence of `TextA` in the list ?
I know you can do like this

```
if($("select["value="TextA"]").length)
{
   //The item is present
}
```

However the above wont work as I dont have a value tag inside the select.
How can I adjust the above for my case ?

I looked at the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646317/how-can-i-check-whether-a-option-already-exist-in-select-by-jquery) but none tell you how to deal with my case in which the value property is missing inside the option tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [**:contains()**](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) as shown :-

```
if($("#mid option:contains('TextA')").length)
{....}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/2304/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:contains()`](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) Selector.

```js
if($("select option:contains('TextA')").length){
   console.log("Item found");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="mname" id="mid" size="15">
  <option>TextA </option>
  <option>TextB </option>
  <option>TextC </option>
</select>
```

Would you please check above snippet?

Comment: thanks for the answer - also for putting in such a great effort. Unfortunately Ill have to go with the first one as that was answered first.

Comment: do not give the same answer. This type of answer is already given first. First check and if your answer is also same as first then give the votes not you also give the same answer.