# Adding to a list

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use javascript to add whatever is in a text-input to a list whenever the user hits a button. This is my function so far:

```
function add(){
    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    var email = form.elements.typer.value

    var select = document.getElementById('users')
    var option = document.createElement("option")
    option.text = email
    select.add(option)
}
```

It works but you can add the same text many times. How can I make the program so that the user can't add the same text many times?

Comment: You can check if there is any text already inside the array before add.

Comment: Look into [sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)

Comment: First you have to check value in option. If exist in select option then you have to ignore otherwise you can add value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/646329/1675954 (instead of alert, add..)

Answer (score 1):

You can have an array where you keep track of all emails that already been added.
Then, before create the option to the `select`, check if it is found in that array, if not, then add, if yes, then tell the user.

See below code

```js
var addedUsers = [];

function add(){
    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    var emailInput = form.elements.typer;
    let email = emailInput.value
    emailInput.value = "";

    if (addedUsers.indexOf(email) == -1){
      addedUsers.push(email)
      var select = document.getElementById('users');
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.text = email;
      select.add(option)
    } else {
      alert("This user is already in the list");
      emailInput.focus()
    }
}
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="typer"/>
  <button onclick="add()" type="button">Add</button>
</form>

<select id="users"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I also have a remove button. Can you factor that in?

Comment: This is my remove function:

Comment: function rem(){
    var form = document.getElementById('form')
    var email = form.elements.typer.value

    var select = document.getElementById('users')
    var options = select.options

    for (var i = 2; i < options.length; i++){
        if(email === options[i].innerHTML){
            select.remove(i)
            break
        }
    }
}

Comment: Please, this is another question. Close this one marking my answer as accepted one, then open a new question with the information you passed above and then after creating this new question click in the `share` button below your new question and pass me the link here.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the text, you can check if it already exists in the list by using includes(). MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

This will return true or false, depending on if the value is already present in the list.